# make a list of int and a list of string into a list of tuple (int,string)

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, int, tuples

I have a list `[1,2,3,...,13]` and a list `['clubs','hearts,'spades','diamonds']`. How do I make a list of tuples looking like...
`[(1,hearts),(1,clubs),(1,spades),(1,diamonds),(2,hearts)...` and so on?

I have tried using a list comprehension but can't figure it out.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I need it in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html),

```
rank = [1, 2, 3]
suit = ['clubs', 'hearts', 'spades']
card = [(a, b) for a in rank for b in suit]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using [product from itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

```
from itertools import product
rank = range(1,14)
suit = ['clubs','hearts','spades','diamonds']
print( list(product(rank, suit)) )
```

you get:

```
[(1, 'clubs'), (1, 'hearts'), (1, 'spades'), (1, 'diamonds'), (2, 'clubs'), (2, 'hearts'), (2, 'spades'), (2, 'diamonds'), (3, 'clubs'), (3, 'hearts'), (3, 'spades'), (3, 'diamonds'), (4, 'clubs'), (4, 'hearts'), (4, 'spades'), (4, 'diamonds'), (5, 'clubs'), (5, 'hearts'), (5, 'spades'), (5, 'diamonds'), (6, 'clubs'), (6, 'hearts'), (6, 'spades'), (6, 'diamonds'), (7, 'clubs'), (7, 'hearts'), (7, 'spades'), (7, 'diamonds'), (8, 'clubs'), (8, 'hearts'), (8, 'spades'), (8, 'diamonds'), (9, 'clubs'), (9, 'hearts'), (9, 'spades'), (9, 'diamonds'), (10, 'clubs'), (10, 'hearts'), (10, 'spades'), (10, 'diamonds'), (11, 'clubs'), (11, 'hearts'), (11, 'spades'), (11, 'diamonds'), (12, 'clubs'), (12, 'hearts'), (12, 'spades'), (12, 'diamonds'), (13, 'clubs'), (13, 'hearts'), (13, 'spades'), (13, 'diamonds')]
```